# jQuery not firing in child aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Edit Your Password" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Profile.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Edit-Password.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Profile.Edit_Password" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".pass2").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test');
            });
            jQuery(".pass1").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test1');
            });
            jQuery("#txtNewPassword").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test2');
            });
            jQuery(".txtNewPassword").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test2');
            });
            jQuery("#<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID %>").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test2');
            });
        });
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID %>").on('keyup', function () {
                alert('test2');
            });
            jQuery(".pass2").keyup(function() {
                alert('keyup');
            });
        });
        jQuery("#<%=txtNewPassword.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
            alert('test');
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ChildContent1" runat="server"> 
<section>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                    <div>
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="EditPassword" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="pass1" ID="txtNewPassword"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div id="confirm_password_field" class="control-group">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="EditPassword" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="pass2" ID="txtNewPasswordConfirm"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="light-blue-button" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="EditPassword" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</asp:Content>
```

I tried different methods to get the keyup event but none of them is triggered when I use the page.

Any idea what else I need to check?

Comment: Will you mind adding parse html ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not sure if I understand your request

Comment: I am unable to create an environment where I can execute `asp` files. Kindly share browser rendered html/markup

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4571235/sample.html @RayonDabre

Comment: It doesn't help.. we need the valid html (with jquery reference etc..). Also, it should work: http://jsbin.com/kituvo/edit?html,js,output. Do you have any errors in the `console`?